# Duda con la formula en excel

Tags: excel, formulas, tabla-dinámica, microsoft-office, excel-2013

quisiera saber por que me sale "falso" en la segunda consigna que le pongo a en la función SI:

`````
=SI(G4="X",SI(Y($I$10<=11.8),"desnutricion severa",SI(Y($I$10>=11.9,$I$10<=12.6),"desnutricion moderada",SI(Y($I$10>=12.7,$I$10<=16.9),"normal",SI(Y($I$10>=17,$I$10<=18.9),"sobrepeso",SI(Y($I$10>=19),"obesidad",SI(G5="X",SI(Y(I10<=11.7),"DESNUTRICION SEVERA",SI(Y(I10>=11.8,I10<=12.6),"DESNUTRICION MODERADA",SI(Y(I10>=12.7,I10<=16.9),"NORMAL",SI(Y(I10>=17,I10<=19),"SOBREPESO",SI(Y(I10>=19.1),"OBESIDAD"))))))))))))````
`````

Esa es la fórmula entonces cuando sale g4 si me pone el resultado, pero cuando sale en g5 me sale falso

Me podrían ayudar es para sacar **imc** en Excel con edades

Comment: Tu formula al principio está utilizando referencias absolutas y no hace más que mirar todo el rato la celda `I10` pero en otras utilizas referencias relativas. No tiene mucho sentido, aunque un ejemplo de datos sería útil.